# Fibres of a morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:X\rightarrow S$ a proper morphism, and $s\in S$ a point. If $S$ is locally Noetherian, then what are the properties of the fibre scheme $X_s$ over the Spec of the residue field at $s$? Is this a Noetherian scheme? Is the dimension always finite?

Comment: What if $S$ is already a field? I think you need some sort of hypotheses.

Comment: @Hoot: good point. I myself am not sure about the hypotheses, and I was hoping for some positive results for hypotheses that may be determined by the reader. I am looking for general results though

Comment: @Hoot: I think I want $f$ to be proper!

Comment: Part of being proper is being finite type, and then I think you're fine. Being finite type is stable under base change. So now you've got a scheme of finite type over a field.